# Unable to set correct data using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So, I just started coding in Discord.js V13, and I am facing a bit of a problem.
What happens is, I try to get a channel ID through an interaction and save it in the database, for this I am using Sequelize. But it doesn't seem to be saving the correct data, let me show you the code.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const Welcome = require("../../models/welcome");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("setwelcome")
    .setDescription("Set server welcome channel prefix")
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("welcome")
        .setDescription("Channel ID for the welcome channel.")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async run(client, interaction) {
    if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has("982571544981151785")) {
      return interaction.reply({
        content: "You do not have permissions to perform this command",
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }

    const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("welcome").id;

    console.log(channel);

    try {
      let setWelcome = await Welcome.findOne({
        where: {
          guildID: interaction.guildId,
        },
      });

      if (!setWelcome) {
        const newWelcome = await Welcome.create({
          channelID: channel,
          guildID: interaction.guildId,
        });

         await newWelcome.save().then(() => {
          return interaction.reply({
            content: "Succesfully set welcome channel!",
          });
        });
      } else if (setWelcome) {
        setWelcome.set({
          channelID: channel,
          guildID: interaction.guildId,
        });

        await setWelcome.save().then(() => {
          return interaction.reply({
            content: "Succesfully set welcome channel",
          });
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.name == "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError") {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "This welcome channel is already set!",
        });
      }
    }
  },
};
```

This is the whole code.

What I want it to do: Take the ID and store it in the database as channelID
What it does: Stores the guild ID instead of the channel ID in the database.

I have been trying to fix it for a long time, but there were no improvements I could come up with

```js
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sql = require("../sequelize");

const Welcome = sql.define("welcome", {
  channelID: {
    type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
    unique: true,
  },
  guildID: {
    type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
  },
});

module.exports = Welcome;
```

The Sequelize Model above

Answer (score 0):

If this code is successfully changing the guildID but not the channelID, my only assumption is that you are trying to use duplicate values for channelID and the unique constraint is blocking that action.

The line of code where you await newWelcome.save() and follow it with .then() is also redundant. You should be very careful using await and .then() together like that, as it can lead to unexpected results (I don't believe it has anything to do with the issues you are currently facing, however).

Comment: If there were duplicate values for channelID, then it should have thrown the SequelizeUniqueConstraintError error, it isn't, I am fairly new to using Sequelize, so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possibly. I would try console logging err in that catch block to see if the catch block is being reached. I see that you're logging the channel variable before your DB actions, I take it that value is what you expect it to be? If you aren't getting into the catch block and the channel variable holds the correct value, I'm a little perplexed at why this wouldn't work. Can you also confirm if this isn't working for both the create and update conditions?